# AttributeError: 'Functional' object has no attribute 'predict_segmentation' When importing TensorFlow model Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have successfully trained a Keras model like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras_segmentation.models.unet import vgg_unet

# initaite the model
model = vgg_unet(n_classes=50, input_height=512, input_width=608)

# Train
model.train(
    train_images=train_images,
    train_annotations=train_annotations,
    checkpoints_path="/tmp/vgg_unet_1", epochs=5
)
```

And saved it in hdf5 format with:

```
tf.keras.models.save_model(model,'my_model.hdf5')
```

Then I load my model with

```
model=tf.keras.models.load_model('my_model.hdf5')
```

Finally I want to make a segmentation prediction on a new image with

```
out = model.predict_segmentation(
    inp=image_to_test,
    out_fname="/tmp/out.png"
)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Functional' object has no attribute 'predict_segmentation'
```

What am I doing wrong ?
Is it when I am saving my model or when I am loading it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Where do you get that this predict_segmentation method actually exists?

Comment: Well, it does exist before I am saving the model since I can make a good segmentation prediction with the same code.

Comment: Sure but that is not a standard method of Keras models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`predict_segmentation` isn't a function available in normal Keras models. It looks like it was added after the model was created in the [`keras_segmentation`](https://github.com/divamgupta/image-segmentation-keras/blob/dc830bbd76371aaedbf8cb997bdedca388c544c4/keras_segmentation/models/model_utils.py#L101) library, which might be why Keras couldn't load it again.

I think you have 2 options for this.

1. You could use the line from the code I linked to manually add the function back to the model.

```py
model.predict_segmentation = MethodType(keras_segmentation.predict.predict, model)
```

2. You could create a new `vgg_unet` with the same arguments when you reload the model, and transfer the weights from your `hdf5` file to that model as suggested in the [Keras documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#transfer_learning_example_2).

```py
model = vgg_unet(n_classes=50, input_height=512, input_width=608)
model.load_weights('my_model.hdf5')
```